# Gulp typescript compiling files that I'm not specifying?

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-typescript

My intention is to compile `*.ts` files location in the (And any subdirectories) of `src/main/ts/`.  I have `tsconfig.json` file that looks like this:

```
    {
        "filesGlob": [
            "src/main/ts/**/*.ts"
        ],
        "compilerOptions": {
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "target": "es6"
        }
    }
```

My gulp task looks like this:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
    var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

    gulp.task('default', function() {
      return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js.pipe(gulp.dest("target/main/js"));
    });
```

I was having a compilation issue with some of the files in `src/main/ts/` so I moved these to a directory in the root of the project called temp.

However the gulp task compiles the files in temp as well.  I get errors like these:

```
temp/main/ts/domain/Order.ts(11,11): error TS1146: Declaration expected.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You're missing an import in order.ts. please provide the code in order.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to 
[the tsconfig.json documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), you should use `"include"` (and if needed, `"exclude"`) to specify the files to compile, not `"filesGlob"`